# How to ensure data sent via JSONP is secure?

Tags: php, json, security, encoding, jsonp

I need to ensure that data sent out from a script is as secure as possible. The server-side language is PHP.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:** What I mean is. I need to ensure the data sent from my server cannot do damage to the other server that is retrieving it. I'm not worried about the security or people seeing the data that's being sent, just need to make sure it can't harm the other site.

Comment: Secure against **what**?  Please provide much more detail.

Comment: To prevent tampering with the data? To prevent eavesdropping? "secure" means many different things, and it's entirely dependent on your perceived threats.

Comment: I mean passing in any type of code/functions that could do damage to the site that is is pulling in JSONP data to display on it's site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is totally safe if everything is properly escaped. If your delivered JSON is valid, there is no security risk (assuming that the other side does not use evil `eval` on some of the values).

Comment: @elusive, Can you give me an example of what you mean in regards to being properly escaped?

Comment: @Zoolander: "Properly escaped" means "valid JSON". Take a look at [the JSON spec](http://json.org/) and PHP's [`json_encode()` function](http://php.net/json_encode), which shoud make your life a lot easier on the server-side.

Comment: So to clarify, simply using the json_encode() is all I need to ensure that I am using?

Comment: @Zoolander: `json_encode()` converts almost everything to valid JSON. Yes. You should be OK, then. Just make sure that you feed the correct data to the function. I suggest that you take a look at the output it produces for various values.

Answer (score 1):

JSONP data inherently isn't secure because if anyone has the URL they can access it.
Try sending raw json (without a callback function) to increase security.

It is also a very good idea to send the data using HTTPS / SSL instead of plain http, which can be intercepted on its way from the server to the client.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't think I was clear enough when I meant secure. Please see my update above.

Comment: You cannot simply replace JSONP with JSON. The whole purpose of JSONP is to bypass cross-domain issues. He wouldn't be usign JSONP if he wouldn't need it.

Comment: I'm a n00b. Do you have any tutorial to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can make it a bit securer, if you say its not secure.

Btw.: *never use json to list usernames && passwords or etc. only use it for harmless datas*

if you do something like this,

JQUERY: **$('#obj').load("json.test.php");**

put these codes on the top of the json.test.php

//You have to read the url

```
<?php
    $_domain = "testdomain.com"; //or
    $_domain = "testdomain.com/index.php?_sid="; //or you can check for any parameter
    $getPos = strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"], $_domain);
    if(!empty($getPos) && $getPos >= 0) die("Direct Access is not allowed!");
?>
```

Hope this helps